# Python - Display all the rows with repeated values column in file

Tags: python

i want so search all values in column 5(pipe separated) with entire file and display all those files which contain same value.
NOTE: column 5 may contain multiple values separated by coma(00a0gte69876,2350gte69876)

Input files :-
`01001cee673753|5|011cb88f714093|001c7b203753|1cb34f767093|true|1|OldCPEPool|345311408905370
01001ffb673751|5|0100a044e69876|001c7b673745|00a0gte69876,2350gte69876|true|1|OldCPEPool|134340003134731
010016cww7f62f|5|017422cf6e565b|0016gtf7f62f|10gt828f2a13|true|3|OldCPEPool|141198213475041`

i have tried with this code online but, it gives me error for with open()

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
entries = []
duplicate_entries = []

with open('deviceBinding.org', 'r') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        columns = line.strip().split(',')
        if columns[2] not in entries:
            entries.append(columns[2])
        else:
           duplicate_entries.append(columns[2]) 

if len(duplicate_entries) > 0:
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        with open('deviceBinding.org', 'r') as my_file:
            for line in my_file:
                columns = line.strip().split(',')
                if columns[2] in duplicate_entries:
                    print line.strip()
                    out_file.write(line)
else:
    print "No repetitions"
```

error :
`File "a.py", line 5
    with open('deviceBinding.org', 'r') as my_file:`
please help me on this.

Comment: This question is tagged `perl`. Are you looking for a `perl` solution? It would be useful to give examples of input and output to assist in giving you an answer.

Comment: where did you try this code?

Comment: Post the traceback. Just this error line doesn't explain everything. When you're reading a file, add a sample so that we can replicate your error and find a solution.

Comment: @ Sobrique : file i using contain huge amount of data,thus it take too long time to search using shell script.to reduce searching time i prefer to do this in Python or perl..

Comment: i have tried this code on Linux machine